# Ash Brokerage has 3 ghosts

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When viewing "people you'd work with"

The company ash brokerage has some odd behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/ashbrokerage

[image]

I shouldn't pick on this company - as this is probably happening to many companies.

We should hide this div when we don't have this information.  All three people you'll work with show the same thing...floating empty divs.

**Update**

This also happens on the job listing page:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/112719/net-developer-ash-brokerage?searchTerm=net-developer-ash-brokerage

Comment: So these are not the three ghosts of Christmas then?

Comment: On the CIA or NSA company page, this would be cool though. *"Want to know who you'll work with? We could tell you - but then we'd have to kill you.*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, there's not much point in showing people we don't have any public information about!

I've now updated it so we don't show these blank people on company pages and job listings. In cases like this where we have no information on anybody, we simply hide the section.