# The three ghosts at Ash Brokerage strike again

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

This company and its ghosts has struck us yet again (original issue: [Ash Brokerage has 3 ghosts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339555/ash-brokerage-has-3-ghosts)).  The fix worked when you are at the company page...

Now I'm on Stack Overflow, and an advertisement came up for this same company, but it looks odd—look at who you'll work with:

[image]

Comment: You mean, your company doesn't employ any abstract geometric patterns? Better be careful about that kind of discrimination!

Comment: I would definitively watch it again.

Comment: @CodyGray - I should post on workplace.stackexchange.com to consult some legal advice :-).

Comment: Our industry is not very welcoming towards Kaleidoscope lifeforms as it is. No need to drag them into the spotlight like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report.  You should no longer see the "Who you'll work with..." ad when we have no one to show you, and you should also not see "ghosts" when you do see the ad.